# Find unit singular vectors for two known singular values.

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}-3 & -1 \\ -3& 1\end{pmatrix}$$

- Find the singular values of $σ_1$ and $σ_2$,
- Find unit vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ such that $||Av_1|| =σ_1$ and $||Av_2|| =σ_2$

I figured out  $σ_1$ and $σ_2$ are $\sqrt{18}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ but I can't figure out the second part.

When we have $$A^TA = \begin{pmatrix}18 & 0 \\ 0& 2\end{pmatrix}$$ I thought we were supposed to take each of our lambda values ($18$ and $2$) and subtract them from the diagonals of the $A^TA$ matrix.

For 18 we get $$\begin{pmatrix}18-18 &0 \\ 0& 2-18\end{pmatrix}$$ = $$\begin{pmatrix}0 &0 \\ 0& -16\end{pmatrix}$$ = $$\begin{pmatrix}0 &1 \\ 0& 0\end{pmatrix}$$ So for v1 it should be $$V1=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$.I get v2 as $$V2=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$. However, that answer comes back as incorrect. Not sure what I am doing wrong here, I think I am getting caught up in what exactly I am trying to find? Please for help!

EDIT: OK I am not sure how to do ||Av1|| and ||Av2||. For ||Av1|| am I just multiplying A*v1?
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}-3 & -1 \\ -3& 1\end{pmatrix}$$ * $$V1=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Which equals $$\begin{pmatrix}-3 \\ -3\end{pmatrix}$$
Normalize it and get $$\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$$

But I am getting this answer as incorrect so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be doing.

[image: image link]

Comment: I formatted a half of your post; if you click _edit_ you'll see how this was done and will be able to format the rest. Also, see [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: $\|Av_1\|$ is the (Euclidean) norm of the vector $Av_1$. So, if $Av_1=(x,y)^T$, then $\|Av_1\|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** This seems like a careless mistake. Have you actually calculate the values of $\|Av_1\|$ and $\|Av_2\|$?

Comment: Yes, but I am not doing it right I don't think since the answer is not correct.

Comment: @lordhans You should have $v_1=(1,0)^T$ and $v_2=(0,1)^T$, but somehow you have swapped the two vectors.

Comment: OK I see that was wrong and I updated my calculations, but they are still incorrect. I don't understand if I am doing some of the process wrong or what. @user1551

Comment: Still incorrect? No way. Your homework grading system must be wrong. Wolfram|Alpha [gives the same answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=singular+value+decomposition+%7B%7B-3%2C-1%7D%2C%7B-3%2C1%7D%7D) as mine. We should have $\sigma_1=\sqrt{18},v_1=(1,0)^T,\sigma_2=\sqrt{2},v_2=(0,1)^T$. In fact, $\|Av_1\|=\|(-3,-3)^T\|=\sqrt{(-3)^2+(-3)^2}=\sqrt{18}$ and $v_1$ is a unit vector.

Comment: @lordhans Perhaps the system is so dumb that it expects $(-1,0)^T$ without recognising that $(1,0)^T$ is also a correct answer?

Comment: yeah both of those come back as incorrect. I'm going to go speak to the professor tomorrow and will report back. Thanks for the help though.